# How to call highcharts button from outside

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a simple highcharts which contains a custom button,but here I need to initialize that button from out of highcharts,so that whenever I click on it,it should not hide,only chart should hide. Below is my code ,can anyone please help me on it.I have updated the code in this plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/YSLQMoQpKZqFPk0PXhXm?p=preview

### HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

### javascript

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
    'myButton': {       
        text: 'Custom Button',
                onclick: function () {
                    alert('You pressed the button!');
                },        
        theme: {
            class: "myButton highcharts-button highcharts-button-normal",
            id: "myDiamondButton"
        },
        onclick: function () {
                    alert('You pressed the button!');
                }
    }
}

    }

});
$("#myDiamondButton").click(function(){
    $('#container').hide();
});
```

Comment: Try `$('#container svg').hide()`;

Comment: its hiding button also

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish, create the button you wish to stay on the page as a separate element outside the scope of the chart. Remove the 'exporting' option from the chart and then create a new HTML element for the button.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
$("#myDiamondButton").click(function(){
    $('#container').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<button id="myDiamondButton" >Custom Button</button>
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: I got it but in my project there will be multiple charts that will be creating dynamically and I need to have this button in all charts and onclick it should not be hide and it will capture the id of the chart which that button belongs to.

Comment: @carreankush - What is creating the chart dynamically? I would recommend sticking with this approach and creating the buttons dynamically as well.

Comment: What is creating the chart dynamically?,see this plunker to understand-http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3hJcC8pgzZxXPLWpfBw?p=preview , how to create button dynamically and get the id of that particular chart for which button belongs to?

Comment: You can find all chart instances in `Highcharts.charts` array. So you can for example save particular chart index in button data attribute and use it when clicking the button to hide an appropriate chart.

Comment: I dint get you, can you please give an example

Comment: @carreankush - Check out this plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/jdXrsjG37DneXbCH6qvi?p=preview . When the chart is dynamically created a button is also created with the corresponding chartid set as a data-attribute. When the button is clicked just the corresponding chart is hidden